# Can't connect to server through socket android

Tags: java, android, sockets, client, server

I'm creating a client-server app, which just send and recieve JSON from java server through sockets.
So it's working via Wi-Fi connection. But when I use mobile data connection, my app can't connect to the server.
Error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /37.59.196.27 (port 8080) after 90000ms
```

Here's my code:
MultiClient.java

```
...
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("37.59.196.27");
    ClientThread ct = new ClientThread(addr, map);
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
...
```

ClientThread.java

```
/*imports here*/
class ClientThread extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private static int counter = 0;
    private int id = counter++;
    private static int threadcount = 0;
    private static String IMEI = "";
    private static String NAME = "";
    static final int PORT = 8080;
    public static int threadCount() {
        return threadcount;
    }
    HashMap<String, String> inputMap;
    private HashMap<String,String> returnMap;
    public HashMap<String, String> getData(){
        return returnMap;
    }
    public ClientThread(InetAddress addr, HashMap<String, String> inputMap) {
        returnMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.inputMap=inputMap;
        System.out.println("Making client " + id);
        threadcount++;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(addr, PORT);
            socket.setSoTimeout(0);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            Log.i("socket", e.getMessage());
            System.err.println("Socket failed");
        }
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            start();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e2) {
                System.err.println("Socket not closed");
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            IMEI = inputMap.get("imei");
            NAME = inputMap.get("name");

            Log.i("ClientThread", "here");
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("imei", IMEI);
            obj.put("name", NAME);
            obj.put("os", inputMap.get("os"));
            obj.put("osVersion", inputMap.get("osVersion"));
            out.println(obj);
            String str = in.readLine();
            //System.out.println(obj);
            //SERVER ANSWER:
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            Object jobj = parser.parse(str);
            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject)jobj;
            String text = jsonObj.get("text").toString();
            Log.i("RESPONSE STRING","Image source:    "+jsonObj.get("imagesrc")+"\nPrediction text: "+text);
           // returnMap.put("imagesrc", jsonObj.get("imagesrc").toString());
           // Log.i("text",text);
            returnMap.put("text", text);
            //System.out.println("Server: "+str);
            out.println("END");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IO Exception");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Socket not closed");
            }
            threadcount--;
        }
    }
}
```

Server doesn't see connections created with mobile data, so it isn't server problem.

Thanks and sorry for my English!

Comment: `So it's working via Wi-Fi connection` Likely you have that server in your LAN. If it is in the LAN, you need to figure out what your public IP is and configure port forwarding on your router to make connections reach your in-lan server. Otherwise you won't connect.

Comment: Server isn't in LAN. I successfully connected from another network(Restoraunt wi-fi for example).

Comment: Maybe your mobile ISP is blocking outgoing connections with port different from `80`?

Comment: I tried to ping google.com:80 and got 'unknown host google.com'. But I successfully browsing all sites with browsers. And the same ping via wi-fi connection goes fine. Maybe there's some feature I doesn't know about using socket connection and mobile data?

Comment: You can't ping a port, ping is ICMP and doesn't have ports. As mentioned, you should do some tests, like trying to use port 80 with your server, and trying to connect to a working server like google.com (port 80), just to see if it connects, even if data is garbage after. Try to narrow your problem or we can't do anything.

Comment: I've got same exception trying to connect to google.com.ua(173.194.113.15 ) java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /173.194.113.15 (port 80) after 90000ms. Wi-fi connection still works fine

Comment: Try to create the socket with a `SocketFactory` from a `Network` obtained through `ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork()` with `NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET` specified. Or by other means if you find better. Check if this doesn't need additional permissions before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was hidden in my firmware, so reinstall solved the problem.